# Custom Module - Object Has No Attribute

Tags: python, object, module

I'm trying to use my own modules but I came across this error and can't seem to figure out how to fix it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaron/Desktop/cg/war.py", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: Deck instance has no attribute 'test'
```

From "war.py":

```
import deck

d = Deck()
test2()
d.test()
```

From "deck.py":

```
class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = self.shuffle()
        self.stackSize = len(self.stack)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.stack.items())

    def shuffle(self):
        return {'2c': 'cards/2c.png', '3c': 'cards/3c.png', '4c': 'cards/4c.png', \
                '5c': 'cards/5c.png', '6c': 'cards/6c.png', '7c': 'cards/7c.png', \
                '8c': 'cards/8c.png', '9c': 'cards/9c.png', '10c': 'cards/10c.png', \
                'jc': 'cards/jc.png', 'qc': 'cards/qc.png', 'kc': 'cards/kc.png',
                'ac': 'cards/ac.png'} #continue w/ other suits


    def test():
        print("hello")

def test2():
    print("hello2")
```

When running "war.py," `test2()` works and prints "hello".
`d.test()` does NOT work, and gives the error above. How can I fix this?

In the long run, I'm hoping to use the Deck class in other "card game classes" so I don't need to constantly rewrite it. I would like to simply import Deck and use it, so if I'm doing this incorrectly please let me know!

Comment: are you sure you are not getting `TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`? since you dont state an argument, ie `self`

Comment: @RNar: The program won't get that far as presented, but that error will be encountered, once other problems are fixed.  I addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Deck class isn't being found because it isn't in your current name space. To use it, you need to refer to it using the module name. You'll have the same problem with the test2 function.  Change war.py to look like this:

```
import deck

d = deck.Deck()
deck.test2()
d.test()
```

Another error you will encounter is that your Deck.test method doesn't expect any parameters, but needs to. Add "self" (without quotes) between the parentheses.

Comment: Adding "self" as a parameter to `test()` seemed to get it to work. I wasn't aware you needed a "self" param if you weren't altering the object in some way. Is the `deck.Deck()` truly necessary, because I didn't need it to get my code to work properly.

Comment: @Aaron: With the code you posted, it's necessary. With the code you actually ran, we can't tell. This is one of the reasons you should always post code you actually ran, and preferably, you should run the posted code in a fresh interpreter session to make sure code you ran earlier isn't screwing with things.

Comment: if all you have is `import deck` and not something like `from deck import *` (not recommended), then yes, it is.

Comment: @Aaron: Are you using version 3 or 2? I'm using 2.7 and got errors before using `deck.Deck()`. I've not used 3 and don't have access to it, so YMMV if you're using a newer version. Also, if you do something like `from deck import Deck`, then the Deck class will be in your namespace and your code would work, but - as @user2357112 - mentioned, that's not what you posted above.  That said, `import Deck` is usually preferred over `from deck import Deck` to avoid name space contamination.

Comment: The code I ran was only altered by adding the "self" param to `test()`. Changing my `war.py` class to include `deck.Deck()` threw `AttributeError: 'classobj' object has no attribute 'Deck'`. I'm running `2.9.9a0 (IronPython 2.9.9a0 DEBUG (2.9.0.0) on Mono 4.0.30319.17020 (32-bit))` if that helps.

Comment: @Aaron: 2.9 isn't a version of standard Python, that must be the IronPython version number. I don't know if IronPython changed how things work and don't have access to it. That said, I would be surprised if `import deck` and then `d = Deck()` worked; I still suspect the code has something like `from deck import ...` somewhere. Back to your first comment, yes, methods receive the object as the first parameter, so at least one parameter needs to be specified; 'self' is the conventional name.

Comment: @PTBNL The version I'm running was used for a programming class I took and is contained in the IDE the professor wanted us to use. The code works  in the IDE so as long as it works there, it's fine for now. I'll keep your answer in mind when I move past this class and work independently on projects!